# Redirect to HTTPS from HTTP results in infinite redirects - nodejs?

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, https, openshift

I'm using Express Framework.

I want to redirect users who visit my http://mypage.com to https://mypage.com

I tried this middleware:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    if(req.secure)
      next();
    else
      res.redirect('https://'+res.get('host')+res.originalUrl);
});
```

I also tried `if(req.protocol == 'https')`

This works very well in local environment. I get redirected to `https://localhost:3000` when I visit `http://localhost:3000`

But, when I upload it to OpenShift, I get an infinite redirect error.

What could have gone wrong? My main intention is to redirect user to see **HTTPS** all the time.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
var express = require('express');
var requireHTTPS = require('https');    
var redirect = express();
var redirectServer = http.createServer(redirect);
redirect.use(function requireHTTPS(req, res, next) { 
if (!req.secure) {
 return res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
}
next();
})
redirectServer.listen(3000);
```

Comment: is `requireHTTPS` is a wrapper for HTTPS requests?

Comment: yes..you can add this to the above code`var requireHTTPS = require('https');`